# Login error with android studio and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

I am using Firebase in Android Studio. For login a general users register with their phone number and password and it works phone. I am trying to add within this code that if the admin person enters specific details for an admin login (hardcode it) that it will then show a specific Admin Home Page class I have created and not the general home class. What am I doing wrong for this to work?

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    //Check if user not exist in Database
    if(dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {
        //Get user information
        mDialog.dismiss();
        User user = dataSnapshot.child(editPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
        assert user != null;
        user.setPhone(editPhone.getText().toString());//set phone
        if (user.getPassword().equals(editPassword.getText().toString())) {

            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Home.class);
            Common.currentUser = user;
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Wrong password!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    else if (editPhone.getText().toString().equals("admin") && editPassword.getText().toString().equals("admin")) {
        Intent AdminHomeIntent = new Intent(SignIn.this, AdminHome.class);
        startActivity(AdminHomeIntent);
        finish();

    }
    else{
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exist in database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help with just the code that you shared. 1) Please update your question to include the JSON at the `dataSnapshot` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) It also would be helpful to see the minimal-but-complete code that attaches the listener to the database, so that we can see what you're reading from. 3) What does your `User` class look like? 4) What happens when you step through the code? Which line goes wrong?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i don't think there is anything wrong with code. He just want user to redirect different activity according to their roles. It  can be done in different ways.

Comment: Please post your database structure so we can provide proper solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

Look always try to use lowercase word for naming any type of variable otherwise java will drive you crazy. Try to use  admin_home_intent instead of AdminHomeIntent** also check your user class and datasnapshot line properly.